# Detecting when a selection is made in a combobox without using Change event

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently testing an AS£/Flash app I've developed and I've come across this issue. I have three combos on stage Country, Region and city they are all populated by data from a mySQL DB via PHP.Everything works swimmingly... or so I thought.

When the frame is loaded only the countries combo is populated. Once a selection is made there is an on CHANGE event which triggers the population of the region combo which in turn, once a selection is made, populates the city combo. My problem is that If a  user selects a country and then changes their mind and selects another and repats this procees severl times over... the CHANGE event fires each time the users changes their mind. The knock on effect is that by the time they come to actually select the city the database receives requests from the previous selections.

Is there a way of getting round this...? to have an event listener on selection rather than change perhaps..? I've scoured the web but found nothing that helps...

Help would be appreciated and warmly received..

Comment: @seand,@kamal, Thanks both for your suggestions. I thought I'd missed something obvious but by your answers it appears not. The timer option adds additional layer of compexity which I'd rather avoid. So, picking up on what kamal suggested I'm goiong to opt to disable the combo once a selection is made. That way I avoid the mutliple calls to the DB with one line of code... Thanks again for your help. I'll mark kamels answer as the chosen answer because it led me to my final conclusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better avoid the user to stop selecting another country until the region of the particular selcted country is getting load.Like have some loader or progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a timer in your change event handler. Every time change event handler fires stop and restart the timer. Finally at some point you will have a timer that completes because no more changes are happening. When the timer completes then make your request.

```
var _delay:int = 1000; // 1 second delay
var _t:Timer = new Timer(_delay, 1);
_t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerHandler);
var _comboBox:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
_comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
  if(_t.running)
    _t.stop();
  _t.start();
}

function timerHandler(event:TimerHandler):void
{
  // make call to fetch data
}
```

Another solution would be to store the responses in a Dictionary object and check the Dictionary each time a change event fires. This will minimize the requests to the server.